# Argument Error in Password Resets Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following the tutorial in [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?autoplay=true) to create a "forgot my password" link. I'm running into problems when creating a cookie for the password reset. Here is the error:

```
ArgumentError in PasswordResetsController#create 
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
Rails.root: C:/Sites/application

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:37:in `create_remember_token'
app/models/user.rb:29:in `send_password_reset'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

../app/models/user.rb - line 28 is `remember_token(:password_reset_token)`

```
before_save :create_remember_token
before_create { create_remember_token(:remember_token) }

def send_password_reset
  create_remember_token(:password_reset_token)
  save!
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end

private
def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

../app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions."
  end

  def edit
@user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end
end
```

../app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

def sign_out
  current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

private

  def user_from_remember_token
    remember_token = cookies[:remember_token]
    User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token) unless remember_token.nil?
  end
end
```

If I change the way I find the user in my controller to: `user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])` the first error dissapears. I can only think that this is telling me that I'm calling the user incorrectly, and not assigning the new token to it on reset.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the Railscast, where you have the "remember_token" method, they use a "generate_token" method that was added to the User class. That kind of typo might not be the problem, of course, but if it were the error message would make sense (a method that didn't previously exist wouldn't expect any arguments).

Comment: i know I'm getting totally confused with the token allocation. I had previously developed a method for creating a cookie and wanted to keep going with the same method, but I guess I got stuck trying to merge the two. I've updated my user.rb to include the info and I've also added my helper.

Comment: I don't see where you have a remember_token method defined anywhere. You have a method called create_remember_token, which creates a class variable called remember_token. It seems to me like when you call "remember_token(:password_reset_token)", you are getting an error because "remember_token" is a class variable (shouldn't have arguments), but you are passing it an argument as if it were your create_remember_token method.

Comment: Steve, you are right. I've updated the code to call `create_remember_token(:password_reset_token)` and added to the user.rb file `before_create { create_remember_token(:remember_token) }`. I'm still getting 3 errors.

Comment: The version of this function in the tutorial takes an argument (representing the column name to check) so it can make sure the token value is unique. It also uses that argument to figure out in which column to save the token value. In your version of the method you don't pass an argument - instead you automatically save it in the remember_token column. You are getting the error because you are passing an argument to `create_remember_token` but it isn't expecting one. You will need to modify the method to take an argument so it knows what column its supposed to save the generated token in.

Comment: ...and this is where my lack of experience gets me into trouble. Creating an argument seems to clear up the password reset, but then causes big problems for my sign-up form. More research and reading for me! I know everyone has been here when they were learning, but boy it can be frustrating! Steve, thanks for your help!